# Any way to allow non validated (public visitors) to search the PCP pages available for an event?

Tags: civievent, drupal, extension, search, pcp

Still evaluating CIVICRM for use by my organisation and I love most of the functionality.

One thing I need, and I'm surprised it's not core functionality - or perhaps it is and I haven't found it yet.....

Having created an event (a sponsored cycle ride in my case) and having participants register and create PCP pages, is there any way to allow a member of the public (i.e. not a logged in registered user) to search the PCP pages available for the event in order to find a particular participant they want to sponsor?

I've extended this somewhat by adding the PCP for Teams extension from uk.co.vedaconsulting.pcpteams so would need to integrate with that and search for individuals or teams.....

Comment: what CMS are you planning on using?

Comment: Not set on anything yet, but Drupal seems to be the best choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a working example of a PCP site using that specific Veda Extension as a basis. I’ve made some small edits thus far and have committed them back upstream;

https://secure.thewellspringfoundation.org

We decided to organIze the View (list of Team and Individual PCP pages) as a Leaderboard (based on funds raised thus far) but that could easily be an Exposed Search Term in the View.

Comment: Nice nice (6 to go) nice

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks really good. Just what I'm after. Is there some documentation you can point me to that will explain how to set that up please?

Comment: No sorry no documentation yet - it’s all still pretty fresh; I need to find some time to have a second pass at it, clean it out / eliminate our false starts

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal and CiviCRM Entity and Views then you can build Views that would function as your PCP search/results feature